# How do I only Insert columns that are in my viewModel using entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to insert new records into a database table using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework from a ViewModel. I want the generated INSERT SQL statement to only include the columns in my View Model, and not every column in the domain model. Here is the test code I am using.

My `ViewModel` class

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public string column1 {get; set;}
    public string column2 { get; set; }
}
```

My domain model class

```
public partial class Entity1Table
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string column1 { get; set; }
    public string column2 { get; set; }
    public string column3 { get; set; }
}
```

My controller action where I'm inserting the data. I will be populating the data with a view but I populate the `ViewModel` class manually here for simplicity.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //db is my data context
   Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel1,Entity1Table>().ReverseMap();
   var myViewModel = new ViewModel1 { column1 = "testData1", column2 = "testData2" };
   var InsertThis = Mapper.Map<ViewModel1, Entity1Table>(myViewModel);

   db.Entity1Table.Add(InsertThis);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return View();
}
```

When I view the SQL generated from this code it looks like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Entity1Table]([column1], [column2], [column3])
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[Entity1Table]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()

-- @0: 'testData1' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 30)
-- @1: 'testData2' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 30)
-- Executing at 11/29/2014 11:38:17 PM -06:00
-- Completed in 45 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

As you can see here, Entity Framework is inserting `NULL` into column3, even though there is no parameter, as it is part of the model. I have tables with hundreds of columns and I do not want to insert all of these NULLS, as I want to be able to use default values in the database, and I want my INSERTS to look cleaner without the extra NULLS.

Can this be done with Entity Framework?

Comment: What is the default value in the database? Why isn't `null` appropriate is you don't enter anything?

Comment: Since EF is inserting a new row what should it insert then? If you don't specify the value when creating a new row and the column is nullable database will leave it null so there is no difference... Anyways, EF always insert values for all columns and the only way I can think of changing is would be to create you own interceptor but this would be quite complicated and will give you no apparent benefit.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. That's good to know. It just seems odd to have to insert hundreds of NULLS into a very wide table. I thought maybe there was a way to only insert columns that have parameters. @StephenMuecke yes the data is correct, but I'm not sure what would happen if I had default bindings in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Relational databases the way of doing that is using Null or Default value for the properties you don't want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some default value for your data columns and if u try to insert only limited columns than your default values get inserted in your sql table. EF won't affect the default values set by Sql.